# TChromium или его аналоги в Delphi 10 Seattle

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, tchromium

Понадобился компонент *TChromium* в *Delphi* проекте.

Но столкнулся с проблемой - на гитхабе лежит версия максимум под XE5. А используется Delphi 10 Seattle.

У кого-нибудь получалось всё же использовать в своих проектах наDelphi 10 Seattle *TChromium*? Если да, как смогли его все же интегрировать, ибо у меня *IDE* в глухую отказывается его воспринимать.
И если же нет, то существуют ли какие-нибудь аналоги, по функциональности?

Comment: У Delphi нет версии, которая называется XE10. Возможно вы имеете ввиду 10 Seattle или 10.1 Berlin

Comment: @Kromster 10 seattle

Comment: Есть EmbededWB который юзает движок IE. Официально уже не развивается, но есть вариант допиленный до 10 Berlin: https://github.com/littleearth/Delphi-EmbeddedWB

Comment: @zed, как там с интерпретацией js, в т.ч. jQuery? Ибо работать придется со страницами, которые их используют.

Comment: Там с этим так же, как и в установленном в системе IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку пришлось столкнуться с аналогичной необходимостью в компоненте для работы с Chromium в дружественном проекте, даю ссылку на рабочий обновляемый проект на гите: [CEF4Delphi, набор инструментов, позволяющий использовать Chromium в Delphi приложениях](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi)